# How to use Ghostscript to embed fonts (ttf) into PDFs?

Tags: pdf, fonts, pdf-generation, ghostscript, postscript

I modify my pdf structure adding this:

```
/F1 << 
/Type /Font /Subtype /TrueType /BaseFont /MyFont /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding /FontDescriptor 3 0 R /FirstChar 32 /LastChar 255 >>
```

Then, I printed a simple string with

```
BT
  /F1 24. Tf
  (Hello world!) Tj
ET
```

then finally, to save my final pdf, i used `pdftk input.pdf output out.pdf`.
The problem is that I can't see the added string.

Using ghostscript, I'm trying to embed glyphs for my font (myfont.ttf), so I can use them in my pdf file.
To do that I tried the command:

```
gs \
   -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen \
   -dCompressFonts=true \
   -dSubsetFonts=true \
   -dNOPAUSE \
   -dBATCH \
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
   -sOutputFile=output.pdf \
   -c "<</NeverEmbed [ ]>> setdistillerparams" \
   -f input.pdf
```

But when I go to extract fonts with `mutool extract output.pdf`, I always get 6 fonts, with the only difference that now they are in cff format (before it extracted pfa files), and the pdf takes up much less space.
The problem is that there is no trace of the new font.
So I finally tried

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

but I have the same result.
I specify that the myfont.tff file is in the same folder where the pdf file is located, and in fact no file opening error is returned.

Comment: Why are you expecting to see a font embedded ? Does input.pdf contain fonts which are not embedded ? What do you mean when you say "I specify that the myfont.tff file is in the same folder where the pdf file is located" ? What command line are you using to do that, or how have you modified fontmap/cidfmap  ?

Comment: @KenS Thanks for the reply, now I specified better what I did and what I expect to happen.

Comment: I'm not clear on where Ghostscript enters into this, since you say you are using pdftk. However, if you have a PDF which requests a font but does not embed it then Ghostscript and the pdfwrite device should probably embed **a** font. You still haven't explained how you are telling Ghostscript to use 'myfont/ttf' by the way, and you do need to make sure the the font name of that font is '/MyFont' or whatever. TBH the best thing you really need to supply the PDF file and font, along with a command line.